# How can i show clustered image after kmeans?

Tags: c++, opencv, type-conversion, k-means

I want to use an array  as an input to k means algorithm .That array has the values of displacement in x and y direction and is a result of Lucas Kanade optical flow estimation. The code is following :

EDITED  :

```
int number_of_features=150;
// Lucas Kanade optical flow 
cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK(frame1_1C,frame2_1C,pyramid1,pyramid2,frame1_features,frame2_features,number_of_features,optical_flow_window, 5,optical_flow_found_feature, optical_flow_feature_error,optical_flow_termination_criteria, 0 );

float Dx[150],Dy[150]; // displacement matrices
float  Dis[150][2]; // total displacement matrix

int K=2; // clusters selected
Mat bestLabels, centers;

for(int i = 0; i < number_of_features; i++)
{
CvPoint p,q;
p.x = (int) frame1_features[i].x;
p.y = (int) frame1_features[i].y;
q.x = (int) frame2_features[i].x;
q.y = (int) frame2_features[i].y;

//displacements
Dx[i]=p.x-q.x;
Dy[i]=p.y-q.y;

Dis[i][0] = Dx[i];
Dis[i][1] = Dy[i];

}


// k means algorithm


// Creating Mat for Input data
cv::Mat flt_Dis(150, 2, CV_32F, Dis);

cv::kmeans(flt_Dis, K, bestLabels,TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0),3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

I have solved my previous problem , now i want to show the clustered image. I guess bestLabels store the indices for each element , e.g. if it is categorized to 0th or 1st category. Am  I right ?? How can I show the clustered image ?

Comment: if you want to be helped, please take more time to format the code and give all informations on your problem. What is `cv::kmeans` ? `cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK` ? etc.

Comment: I think someone with experience on image processing can understand . cv::kmeans is the algorithm kmeans and cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK is the function which estimates the optical flow on a sparse set of points using Lucas Kanade method .

Comment: No, you can't. Just convert your matrix to  float type with "matrix.convertTo(flt_matrix, CV_32F)", and use that

Comment: I am not sure if it works .. I tried this : 
cv::Mat flt_Dis(150, 2, CV_32F, Dis);

Comment: No, you need convertTo

Comment: @Miki    error: request for member ‘convertTo’ in ‘matrix’, which is of non-class type ‘int [150][2]’ 
I think convertTo can only be used for Mat type.

Answer (score 0):

K-means *can* be *implemented* to work on integers. You just have to do it.

The result will not be integer though.

Comment: Do you mean like suggested above ?

Comment: No, the suggestion in the comments is to convert your data to float, then run cv::kmeans. My suggestion is to write `yourown::integerkmeans`.

Comment: Could you please explain me what is going wrong in the code above ?

Comment: You have a matrix of integers, but the function expects a matrix of floats. Thus, an error.